# blue-white striped rows pattern is lost with Datatables 1.10 + Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using Bootstrap 3 + Datatables 1.09 and everything is fine. I tried to  upgrade to Datatables 1.10 and the blue-white striped pattern of my tables is not appearing anymore. If I add the class "table table-striped" to my table, the striped pattern is grey-white. How can I recover my original blue striped pattern?
Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bootstrap 3 example](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) on the DataTables site indeed shows a table with grey/white pattern, this style is defined in Bootstrap CSS file. It's hard to say why the style the lost after the upgrade without looking at your CSS files and their order.

To override this pattern, add the following code before the closing `</head>` tag and add `table-striped` class to your table.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* BOOTSTRAP 3 TWEAKS */
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2n+1),
.table-striped > tbody > tr.odd {
    background-color: #D9EDF7;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr.even {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>
```

**UPDATE**: Updated the CSS to color the even rows as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's still grey with your modification but strangely enough, it works if I substitute even for odd (of course the blue rows are the even ones).

Comment: Updated the code to color the even rows as well. Please note that this tweak will affect all Bootstrap tables. If you want to color only DataTables-powered tables, replace `.table-striped` with `.table-striped.dataTable`.

Comment: Still grey and white with your modification. White and blue if I swap odd and even.

Comment: When I use this example (http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) and add the CSS code before the closing `</head>` tag, it works. Need to see your HTML/CSS files to explain why they behave differently.

Comment: Thanks again Gyrocode. Problem probably on my side. I accept your answer. Have a good day.